# Can I make a virtual machine out of a Windows XP physical machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I would like to switch to Linux, but I need some stuff on my Windows XP install.  I know that VMWare Workstation can convert a physical machine into a virtual machine, but it's $189.  :-/

Are there any more cost-effective options?  I don't mind paying a bit for it.  I just am not willing to part with $189 for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Vmware P2V - http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/overview.html , then the free VM player

http://www.vmware.com/download/player/

Some other VM software also supports the VMWare images.

Answer (score 6):

Virtual Box is free, and the latest version has full support for accelerated 3D graphics.

There is a forum post about creating a VDI image from an existing Win XP system here: 
 http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=1404

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is better known as a ["Physical to Virtual"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual) migration, or P2V in short.

I have done this once manually and I know it didn't go very smoothly. Don't remember the exact steps I took, but it was something like this:

- Take a clone of your windows xp system harddrive (I used a Bart PE bootable cd with ghost on it).
- Install a virtual server of your choice and create a virtual machine in it.
- Restore the clone of your harddrive into the new machine (also booting it with Bart PE to do that).

Comment: I used Vmware's converter utility (link in my answer) and I have to say it was perfect! On my old laptop, I ran the utility with a external hard drive in and it converted it without any down time. I then was able to boot the VM from my new laptop flawlessly (other than reactivating windows due to hardware change). I would recommend Vmware Converter to anyone!